# Permission denied when trying to export CSV in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql

When trying to create a csv file in Postgres 11, I get the error "Permission denied" I am using windows 10

I have tried different methods found in different webs to no avail, the methods I have tried are: using the Documents folder, using the D:, C:, drive and adding permission in the security section of the folder properties. None of these solutions has worked.
I have also tried adding the Postgres user in the Services (Administrative Tools) however that did not work either.

```
test=# \copy (SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN car ON car.id = person.car_id) TO 'c:/desktop' DELIMITER ',' csv HEADER;
```

I was expecting to get the csv file, however, I get:

```
c:/desktop: Permission denied
```

Comment: Add the account you used when running posgresql as your local administrators group.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a **file name**, not a directory, e.g. `TO 'c:/desktop/export.txt'`.

But on Windows there is no real (physical) directory `c:\Desktop`, that's a "virtual" directory simulated by the Windows explorer. The actual directory is inside the current user's `%USERPROFILE%` directory, e.g. `c:\Users\cuet\Desktop`.

You need to make sure you specify a valid **physical** path, not a "logical" one. e.g.

```
TO 'c:/Users/cuet/Desktop/export.txt'
```

(assuming your Windows user is `cuet`)

To find the correct path for your desktop you can use:

```
echo %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

In a Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`)

Comment: Hello, this worked. I was making such a rookie mistake. I am totally new to this so I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.